# What is the role of and args() statement, the exception thrown: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, frameworks, aop

I get the exception **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut** if I run the below code

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class EmployeeServiceAspect {
    
    @After(value = "execution(* com.boot.aop.service.EmployeeService.*(..))")
    public void beforeAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint, String empId, String firstName, String lastName) {
        System.out.println("Before Method: " + joinPoint.getSignature());
        System.out.println("Creating Employee with first name - " + firstName + ", last name - " + lastName
                + " and id - " + empId);
    }

}
```

But the code runs fine if I put **and args(...)** as mentioned below.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class EmployeeServiceAspect {
    
    @After(value = "execution(* com.boot.aop.service.EmployeeService.*(..)) and args(empId,firstName,lastName)")
    public void beforeAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint, String empId, String firstName, String lastName) {
        System.out.println("Before Method: " + joinPoint.getSignature());
        System.out.println("Creating Employee with first name - " + firstName + ", last name - " + lastName
                + " and id - " + empId);
    }

}
```

So Please let me know what is the role of below statement which resolves the error.

> and args(empId,firstName,lastName)

Comment: With args you tell that the method arguments matched by the pointcut should be passed in to the advice. With that they also become part of the advice. So only a method using 3 String parameters will now match and the values of those String parameters are passed into the advice. If you leave this out AspectJ has no way of knowing what those 3 String arguments are (hence the error without the args).

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might want to try looking into manuals or other type of documentation sometimes. That would answer your question much more quickly than asking a simple question here and waiting for answers or comments. Please, in this case  refer to [Spring manual, section "Passing Parameters to Advice"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params-passing).